# GWT - DockLayoutPanel doesn't work as expected

Tags: css, gwt, layout, docklayoutpanel

I wan't to create a simple page using DockLayoutPanel,
and I don't know why the main child in that panel doesn't get centered could anybody help?

```
public class Spr implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        DockLayoutPanel panel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(panel);
        panel.add(new HTML("center"));
    }
}
```

This just displays "center" in the top-left corner, while I expect it to display it in the middle of the page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have only added content to the center panel of the DockLayoutPanel.

Try adding left, right, north, etc.. to create other panels with DockLayoutPanel. You could add empty HTML:

```
panel.addNorth(new HTML(""), 2);
```

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html

Answer (score 0):

The center panel occupies all available space in the container. That's the reason you see the label displayed in the top left corner. Try setting other panels - south, west, north etc. Then you will get see desired behaviour.